# http call to get Insight Metrics in json format

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Google Analytics makes available in json format a database of all metrics and dimensions: [Google Analytics Metrics and Dimensions Metadata](https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/metadata/ga/columns?pp=1)

Does Facebook make available such feature for [Insight Metrics](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/insights#reading)?

Comment: I've never seen it. Partially you can achieve it via https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ I mean if you do test queries against "Graph API Explorer" app instead of your own, it should produce some dummy data. At least you can see if query generates data when your app produces nothing for this kind of query.

Comment: I am surprised this information is not easily available. Google Analytics frequently updates dimensions and metrics.  It is nice to easily pull in this data rather than manually have to enter it into your database.